# About Google Play review

Tags: google-play

It's been three weeks since I applied for the release of the app from the Google Play Console.
It is still under review.
This time it's just a minor display improvement, but why is it taking so long?
I've heard that the coronavirus is having an impact, but this time it's too late, and I can't release the iOS app, which has already been reviewed, at the same time.
Is there something wrong with Google right now?
Am I the only one taking this long? How is everyone else doing?

Comment: Chat inquiries don't work at all.
There is no response to email inquiries even after a week.
Of course the review is not over yet.
what happened to google...

Answer (score 0):

[By default](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en), your app will use standard publishing. Certain apps may be subject to extended reviews, which may result in review times of up to 7 days or longer in exceptional cases.

I suggest to talk with chat support to speed up the review process, since you already exceeded the 7 day review period, they will review it manually and publish it